# How to merge multiple numbers into one number like 4,0,0 into 400 without stdlib

Tags: c, bit-shift

I'm trying to parse a file that has following data eg:

```
MAGICNUMBER 400
```

4 is = 0x34
0 is = 0x30

4
0
0
are different unsigned chars

what i want is those different chars  to be converted into

```
unsigned int x = 400;
```

when parsing them into my program i want to merge them into one integer i tried bitshifting but it didn't work and i probably did it very wrong and got a very large number probably due misunderstanding of something, what i'm susposed to do to merge those numbers without string tricks and without using std but only using bitshift with a explanation how it works?

Comment: *"I tried bitshifting but it didn't work"* please post the code  you tried.

Comment: What does bit shifting have anything to do with this. Not that you couldn't find some way to use it, but why would you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each digit is `c - '0'`. When you get a new digit, you know that prior ones are one decimal place greater, so you multiply the current number by 10 and add the new digit:

```
char *s = "400";
int sum = 0;

while(*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
    sum = 10 * sum + (*s - '0');
    s++;
}
```